# how to fix KeyError: 'w'. got it while doing string formatting in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to print the decimal, octal, hex and binary representation of a given number with format :

```
number = int(input())
w = len('{0:b}'.format(number))
print("{0:{w}d} {0:{w}o} {0:{w}X} {0:{w}b}".format(number))
```

The format that I am expecting is as below (say for input 17):

```
17    21    11 10001
```

Comment: what are you actually getting? I don't know what is `i` in your code. Just change the format to `format(number, w=w)` and it will work...

Comment: yes It worked. I forgot to replace i with number.

Comment: if you want to just write `w` consider swithcing to `f-strings`:  `print(f"{number:{w}d} {number:{w}o} {number:{w}X} {number:{w}b}")`

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Excellent !! can you help in understanding this code?. what is diference between above two code snippets which you have suggested.

Comment: They are actually pretty much the same! Just different ways python allows us to manipulate strings. In the answer below you have a link to the format docs, and here is [a link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to the f-strings docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `format_spec` keyword arguments for [`format(value[, format_spec])`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> print("{text}".format(text="hello"))
```

Therefore in your case:

```
>>> number = 17
>>> w = len('{0:b}'.format(number))
>>> print("{0:{w}d} {0:{w}o} {0:{w}X} {0:{w}b}".format(number, w=w))
```

if you want `number` variable to be replaced in the `{0}` placeholder and `w` variable in `{w}` placeholder.

You can find a very similar example in the [`Format examples`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-examples) in the documentation if you search for "nesting":

> Nesting arguments and more complex examples:

```
>>> for align, text in zip('<^>', ['left', 'center', 'right']):
...     '{0:{fill}{align}16}'.format(text, fill=align, align=align)
...
'left<<<<<<<<<<<<'
'^^^^^center^^^^^'
'>>>>>>>>>>>right'
```

Comment: It is mandatory to specify `w=w` because it's a special placeholder. if the `w` in the string was replaced with `1` it could be just `format(number, w)`. interesting anacdote :)